# Finding substring of variable length in bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a string, such as `time=1234`, and I want to extract just the number after the `=` sign. However, this number could be in the range of 0 and 100000 (eg. - `time=1`, `time=23`, `time=99999`, etc.).

I've tried things like `$(string:5:8}`, but this will only work for examples of a certain length.

How do I get the substring of everything after the `=` sign? I would prefer to do it without outside commands like `cut` or `awk`, because I will be running this script on devices that may or may not have that functionality. I know there are examples out there using outside functions, but I am trying to find a solution without the use of such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s=time=1234
time_int=${s##*=}
echo "The content after the = in $s is $time_int"
```

This is a parameter expansion matching everything matching `*=` from the front of the variable -- thus, everything up to and including the last `=`.

If intending this to be non-greedy (that is, to remove only content up to the *first* `=` rather than the *last* `=`), use `${s#*=}` -- a single `#` rather than two.

---

References:

- [The bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](https://web.archive.org/web/20160218211834/http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)
- [BashFAQ #100 ("How do I do string manipulations in bash?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)
- [BashFAQ #73 ("How can I use parameter expansion? How can I get substrings? [...])](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)
- [BashSheet quick-reference, paramater expansion section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameter_Operations)

Answer (score 3):

if `time=` part is constant you can remove prefix by using `${str#time=}`

Let's say you have `str='time=123123'` if you execute `echo ${str#time=}` you would get `123123`

Comment: Since the OP is following best practices by using lower-case variable names, you might do the same.

Comment: ...re: "best practices", see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, defining conventions for naming of environment variables; since shell variables share a namespace (which is to say, for instance, that setting a shell variable named PATH will override the contents of the environment variable PATH), those conventions apply to shell variables as well.

Comment: Thanks updated as per your advice but the reason I used uppercase was so it wouldn't be confused with time= part :)